# How to remove all files from wiki string?

Tags: javascript, regex, mediawiki

I want to remove all files from wiki string like this:

```
[[File:Edvac.jpg|thumb|[[EDVAC]], one of the first stored-program computers]]
```

but the File can contain wiki link, how can I remove all files that can contain wiki links? I've used this regex `/\[\[File:[^\]]+\]\]/` but this will not work for Files that contain wiki link, Note that I don't want to remove wiki links in other places.

Comment: Can there be only one link inside the first paired `[[` and `]]`? No nested links?

Comment: @stribizhev It's better to assume that it can have string likes `[[File:Edvac.jpg|thumb|[[EDVAC]], one of the [[first]] stored-program [[computers]]]]`

Comment: Please check if my answer works as expected, I do not understand now what should be removed here. From what I see, there are no nested wiki links inside wiki links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no nested links inside the the Wiki links like, you can use

```
\[\[File:[^[\]]*(?:\[\[[^[\]]*]][^[\]]*)*]]
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jJ0lY7/1)

```js
var re = /\[\[File:[^[\]]*(?:\[\[[^[\]]*]][^[\]]*)*]]/g; 
var str = 'Some [[File:Edvac.jpg|thumb|[[EDVAC]], one of the first stored-program computers]] text [[File:Edvac.jpg|thumb|text here]]';
var result = str.replace(re, "");
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

*Explanation*:

- `\[\[File:` - a literal sequence `[[File:`
- `[^[\]]*` - zero or more characters other than `[` and `]`
- `(?:\[\[[^[\]]*]][^[\]]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\[\[[^[\]]*]]` - a string of type `[[text without [ and ] inside]]`
  - `[^[\]]*` - zero or more characters other than `[` and `]`
- `]]` - a literal sequence `]]`

Answer (score 1):

Another short variant is: `\[\[File:[^[\]\]]*(\[\[.*]])?[^[\]\]]*]]`. But it is better to include checking for **file:**, **Image:**, **image:**, **Media:** and **media:** because they are also used in many articles for Commons' media embedding:

```
str.replace(/\[\[(file|image|media):[^[\]\]]*(\[\[.*]])?[^[\]\]]*]]/gi, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

File captions can (and, on Wikipedia, sometimes do) contain nested brackets, including other files. You can match balanced brackets with a [recursive regexp](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) like

```
|
  \[\[File:                         # literal [[File:
    (?P<balanced>                   # subpattern for []-balanced content
      (?>[^\[\]]*)                  # zero or more non-bracket chars 
                                    # (with once-only subpattern for efficiency)
      (?:                           # then a (possibly empty) sequence of...

        \[(?&balanced)\]            # []-balanced content in brackets
        (?>[^\[\]]*)                # followed by zero or more non-bracket chars
      )*
    )
  \]\]                              # literal ]]
|x                                  # extended mode flag (ignores whitespace)
```

([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bX1mQ9/1)) although you probably don't want to. (Also, a file caption might well contain unbalanced brackets.)

If you are comfortable with Python, you should try doing it with [mwparserfromhell](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell) which has a robust parser and can identify the file references for you. Something along the lines of

```
import mwparserfromhell

def has_file_prefix(link):
    return str(link.title).strip().startswith('File:')

text = 'I am a wiki page. I contain some images like [[File:Edvac.jpg|thumb|[[EDVAC]], one of the first stored-program computers [[File:Edvac2.jpg| [[nesting|nested]] file with random <nowiki>[[</nowiki> in caption ]] ]] [[ not a file ]] and lots of text.'

wikicode = mwparserfromhell.parse(text)
for file in wikicode.ifilter_wikilinks(matches=has_file_prefix):
    try:
       wikicode.remove(file)
    except ValueError:
       pass # probably tried to remove a nested file when the parent was already removed

print wikicode
```

Comment: This is javascript question.

Comment: Actually it is not. Having a javascript tag on it is no replacement for articulating your requirements, which might or might not be absolute. There is no good wikitext parser in javascript (unless you count node.js as javascript); getting wrong results some of the time might or might not be a problem for your use case. You might be able to deploy server-side processing and interact via AJAX etc. If you don't explain those kind of details in the question, don't expect people to mind-read them.